# Получение вершин графа networkx

Tags: python, networkx

У меня есть circular grpah, в который я добавил вершины:

```
graph = nx.Graph()
add_nodes(('BB', 'IS', 'DV', 'EX', 'EX1', 'EX2', 'EX3'))
nx.draw_circular(graph,
                 node_color='red',
                 node_size=1000,
                 with_labels=True)
```

Меня интересуют координаты этих вершин. Как можно их получить из NX? И можно ли вообще (долго лазил по интернету, не нашел ничего дельного). Если нельзя, то есть ли похожие на NX библиотеки, в которых можно вытащить координаты вершин построенного графа?

Comment: Нашел решение:
Координаты всех ребер графа можно получить при помощи метода circular layout. Выглядит это так:

`graph = nx.Graph()` - 

`pos = nx.circular_layout(graph) # Получение координат вершин`
`print(pos)`

Вывод:
`{'EB': array([1.00000000e+00, 1.98682151e-08]), 'IS': array([-0.50000007,  0.86602542]), 'DV': array([-0.49999993, -0.86602544])}`

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста ваше решение как ответ

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение: Координаты всех ребер графа можно получить при помощи метода circular layout. Выглядит это так:

```
graph = nx.Graph() - pos = nx.circular_layout(graph) # Получение координат вершин print(pos)
```

Вывод: `{'EB': array([1.00000000e+00, 1.98682151e-08]), 'IS': array([-0.50000007,  0.86602542]), 'DV': array([-0.49999993, -0.86602544])}`

Comment: тут graph = nx.Graph() - pos = nx.circular_layout(graph) нет опечатки?